# Codeception: [RuntimeException] Call to undefined method ApiTester::sendDELETE

Tags: yii2, codeception

I'm running API tests with codeception using Yii2. Inside tests folder I have another folder codeception in which I have all the configuration files, and this is where I run my tests.

This is my **codeception.yml** file

```
paths:
    tests: tests
    output: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs
actor_suffix: Tester
extensions:
    enabled:
        - Codeception\Extension\RunFailed
```

And this is my **api.suite.yml**:

```
class_name: ApiTester
    modules:
        enabled:
            - \Helper\Api
            - \Helper\FactoryHelper
            - REST:
                 depends: PhpBrowser
                 url: 'http://apitest.sb.dev/api/'
            - Db:
                 dsn: 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test'
                 user: 'root'
                 password: ''
                 dump: 'codeception/_data/dump.sql'
                 populate: true
                 cleanup: true
                 reconnect: true
            - Yii2:
               configFile: ../config/tests/unit.php
               part: [orm, email]
               cleanup: false
            - DataFactory:
               factories: codeception/_support/factories
               depends: Yii2
```

A typical test I have would have functions from the generated file ApiTesterActions. My problem is that whenever I run a test Ill get an error indicating that ApiTesterActions file is completely not seen. An example:

> Codeception: [RuntimeException] Call to undefined method
>   ApiTester::sendDELETE

removing sendDelete from my test and using any other method that is in that file will also give an error.

Example for test:

```
public function index(ApiTester $I) {
    $I->wantTo('view list via api');
    $I->sendGET($this->_getUrl(), ['client' => 10]);
    $I->seeResponseContainsJson(["data" => $this->menus]);
    $I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
    $I->wantTo("try to view menus with client which doesn't exist");
    $I->sendGET($this->_getUrl(), ['client' => 150]);
    $I->seeResponseCodeIs(403);
    $I->seeResponseIsJson();
    $I->seeResponseContains(Yii::t('app', 'You need permission'));
}
```

What am I doing wrong??!

**Edit: This is the ApiTester.php**

```
/**
 * Inherited Methods
 * @method void wantToTest($text)
 * @method void wantTo($text)
 * @method void execute($callable)
 * @method void expectTo($prediction)
 * @method void expect($prediction)
 * @method void amGoingTo($argumentation)
 * @method void am($role)
 * @method void lookForwardTo($achieveValue)
 * @method void comment($description)
 * @method \Codeception\Lib\Friend haveFriend($name, $actorClass = NULL)
 * 
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD)
*/
class ApiTester extends \Codeception\Actor
{
    use _generated\ApiTesterActions;


    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function loadFixture($name)
    {
        return include 'codeception/fixtures/' . $name . '.php';
    }

    /**

     */
    public function autoAuthenticate($key = '')
    {
        if ($key == '') {
            $key = '17sV24Ku83q-BxeNbXHUWNcBO5iVQxDK';
        }
        return $this->amBearerAuthenticated($key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try running `codecept build` to rebuild regenerated files.

Comment: Tried this a million times. Nothing working 
Codeception really is confusing

Comment: Please show the code of one test file.

Comment: I added a file, but my point is, I tried a million different things, the tests would fail at the first use of a method from ApiTesterActions

Comment: well, we have to figure out what's the single thing that you did wrong :)

Comment: Does `tests/_support/ApiTester.php` file contain this line of code 'use _generated\ApiTesterActions;` inside the class?

Comment: yes it does, and the file is generated all right :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179024/discussion-between-naktibalda-and-mrateb).

Comment: can you add your `tests/_support/ApiTester` file? are the namespaces ok? is there any difference in the class name and file name ?

Comment: Just added this file :)